# PostgreSQL monolingual column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to prevent inserting all characters of all languages except one in a `varchar` column? For example I have a `first name` column that I want be just in Arabic. Should I use regex on that column or it is better to check it in program logic?

Comment: Check constraint with a regex would do best. `(first_name ~* '^[<arabic letters set>]+$')`

Comment: If this is a hard requirement, I would strongly suggest to use a database constraint, rather than program logic, since program tend to have more bugs than database constraints.

Comment: See documentation for [check constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS). Use your regexp as the condition.